# How do I access the luaL_loadbuffer name parameter?

Tags: c++, lua

I've been using the luaL_loadbuffer for many years to load Lua code from within a C++ program. Suddenly I find I need the script to know its own name. Sure, the script in an anonymous function as far as the Lua context is concerned but the C++ framework around it keeps it in a hashmap with a name, the name of the file from which it was loaded to be precise.

I passed that file name into luaL_loadbuffer when I originally wrote the code but I never actually used it. I now need that name so I can have the script compute metrics about its own execution.

luaL_loadbuffer(LuaContext, code, strlen(code), **name**)

I now need to use that **name** from with the Lua context. What's the easiest way to do that?

I'm going to tap the Lua debug function documentation in the meantime while waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When that code is running, `debug.getinfo(1).src` will give you `name`.